# 8085 microprocessor program - sum of even numbers

Tags: microprocessor

I am not able to find my mistakes for the following question:
Calculate the sum of series of even numbers from the list of numbers. The length of the list is in memory location 2200H and the series itself begins from memory location 2201H. Assume the sum to be 8 bit number so you can ignore carries and store the sum at memory location 2210H. I'm using GMUSim8085 to check my answer. Final contents at register B is 00H

Sample problem
2200H= 4H

2201H= 02H

2202H= 03H

2203H= 05H

2204H= 08H

My Code:

```
mvi b,00h
lxi h,2200H
mov c,m
lxi h,2201h
skip2: mov a,m
ani 01h
jnz skip
mov d,a
mov a,b
add d
mov b,a

skip: inx h
dcr c
jnz skip2
hlt
```

Comment: It is good practice to add comments to your code, especially if you want someone else to review it.

Answer (score 1):

`ANI` logically ANDs the accumulator content  with the immediate data and the result   is   placed in the accumulator.

So in your case, the accumulator content for an even number will be `0x00` after executing the instruction `ani 01h`. Hence you the answer will always be `00`.

As Dave Tweed said: *"You need to move the number to the D register before you do the ANI, not after."*

Comment: In other words, you need to move the number to the D register *before* you do the ANI, not after.

Comment: thanks, i forgot that even the result of a logical AND operation is stored in the accumulator